# How to "head" a very long MongoDB return variable

Tags: mongodb

I ran something in the aggregation pipeline and assigned it to a variable.  I'm not sure what the structure of the return object is exactly, and would like some sort of "head" that will let me look at it line-by-line, or some function that let me see what objects are contained in it.  What's the syntax for this?

```
var names = db.inst.aggregate(
    { $group : {
        _id : "$inst.state", 
        names: {$addToSet: "$inst.name"}
    }}
).result
```

How can I interrogate names now?

Comment: Have you tried `printjson(names)`?

Comment: Too long.  It prints zillions of records.

Comment: I doubt it's "zillions" as the aggregation results can be no more than 16MB total.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to get to? What does your final result need to look like?

Comment: It may be less than a zillion, but more than the size of my terminal history, so I still can't see the key names or structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a js script that will output the result and run the script from the shell redirecting the output to the file of your choice,

So if the database you use is db_name and you have saved the script that outputs the results in `print-names-result.js`, just add `printjson(names)` to your existing script, the command will be:

```
mongo db_name print-names-result.js > names.json
```

Then inspect the file `names.json` with an editor.

Of course you can also pipeline the output directly to the `head` command:

```
mongo db_name print-names-result.js | head
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working in the mongo shell.

If you are then what you now have is a JSON object, I am assuming it looks something like this:

```
[
    {"_id": "fred", "names": ["fred", "john"]},
    {"_id": "jack", "names": ["jack", "bill"]}
]
```

So to see what values you have you can just run the command

```
names
```

This will show you all the results in the collection

To see the individual results you can just use the index of the array:

```
names[1]
```

To get to the properties on the items just use dot notation:

```
names[1].names
```

Comment: That is what I want it to look like, but the contents of 'names' are too long to tell.  All I see is a list of what the names are, without being able to scroll high enough to see the key, or outer structure.  How can I interrogate the JSON obect rather than assuming what it looks like?

Comment: But you know what the JSON object looks like as you defined it in your aggregate query. You could run a [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) on your data to try and get a smaller set of data so you can see what the structure is

Comment: `{
    _id : "$inst.state", 
    names: {$addToSet: "$inst.name"}
}` this bit defines the object that is inside your results array. You just need to then work with this object.

Answer (score 1):

The closest analogue to head would be:

Serialize the object using `var s = JSON.stringify(names)`

Extract needed parts from the string with `s.slice(from,to);` - or run regular expression over it to find what you need.

Other than that, you can refer to individual items from the result by array index.